# How to sort SQL result

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have a `SQL query` in which I want to get name of colors depending upon the search parameter. (Database: Oracle10, Frontend: Java)

Table (table1)

```
ID  COLORNAME
--- --------------------
1   Blue
2   Light Blue
3   Dark Blue
4   Dark Red
5   Light Red
6   Red
```

Following is my query to get the list of colors which contains `Red` word (Search parameter is `Red`)

```
select * from table1
where colorname LIKE '%Red%'
```

**Output:**

```
ID  COLORNAME
--- --------------------
4   Dark Red
5   Light Red
6   Red
```

Above output is correct, but I want that `ColorName` starting with `Red` must appear first, and then the colors which contains the word `Red`.

**Expecting:**

```
ID  COLORNAME
--- --------------------
6   Red
4   Dark Red
5   Light Red
```

So how can I achieve this in query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

depends on how you decided that red should be first. 
in your specific case

```
select * 
from table1
where colorname LIKE '%Red%'
order by nullif(colorname , 'Red') nulls first
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(select * from table1 where colorname = 'red')
union
(select * from table1 where colorname like '%red%' and colorname != 'red')
```

edit: thinking about this, it is actually not a guaranteed sort - but will be so in probably all cases.

to make this method guaranteed you have to do this:

```
(select <cols>, colorname, 1 as i from table1 where colorname = 'red')
union
(select <cols>, colorname, 2 as i from table1 where colorname like '%red%' and colorname != 'red')
order by i, colorname
```

or you could use @haki's suggestion

edit again, come to think there actually is a easier way of doing this in some dbms's:

```
select * from table1
where colorname like '%red%'
order by (colorname = 'red') desc, colorname
```

Comment: Thanks for the efforts(and +1)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding a "family" and a "position" to your data model:

```
ID  FAMILY POS COLORNAME  
--- --------------------  
4   Red    20  Dark Red  
5   Red    30  Light Red  
6   Red    10  Red
```

Then you can `order by family, pos, colorname`. It's flexible to define any other sorting schema.

To make it fast, you could put an index on these columns: if you use '%red%', it's probably always a full table scan.

Answer (score 1):

Extending this to more generic criteria, I would think that the exact match would be the one with the minimum length.

So you could:

```
with required_rows as (
  select t.*
         length(colorname)              length_colorname    ,
         min(length(colorname)) over () min_length_colorname
  from   table1
  where  colorname like '%Red%')
select   id,
         colorname
from     required_rows
order by case length_colorname
           when min_length_colorname then 0
           else 1
         end,
         colorname
```

If you didn't need the other rows sorted then you could just order by length(colorname) of course.